# Decoding this kind of JSON with Codable

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have a json that looks like this:

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Apple",
            "price": 44,
            "available": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Pear",
            "price": 27,
            "available": false
        }
    ],
    "some_stuff": [],
    "some_other_stuff": []
}"""
```

My goal is to parse the content of the `data` array, specifically in a struct that doesn't care about the `availibility` attribute. I don't care about the `some_stuff` and `some_other_stuff` returned is that json.

- First question: Can I ignore these properties event if they are part of the response at the same level as "data" which I'm interested in? If so, how do I represent and empty array of a type I ignore because I only get empty arrays? (For that part, I chose to represent it as an array of arbitrary chosen type Int?)

I created a struct:

```
struct Fruit: Codable {
    let name: String
    let price: Int
}
```

And a kind of super struct above:

```
struct WholeResponse: Codable {
    let data: [Fruit]
    let someStuff: [Int?]
    let someOtherStuff: [Int?]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
        case someStuff = "some_stuff"
        case someOtherStuff = "some_other_stuff"
    }

    struct Fruit: Codable {
        let name: String
        let price: Int
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let data = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .data)
        name = try data.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        price = try data.decode(Int.self, forKey: .price)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        var data = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .data)
        try data.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try data.encode(price, forKey: .price)
    }
}
```

But I found myself pretty stuck after doing this:

```
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

let fruits = try jsonDecoder.decode(WholeResponse.self, from: jsonData)
```

I think I am missing something about the representation of my data and perhaps complicating the thing but can you help me get this data array parsed?

Comment: If you don't care about `someStuff` and `someOtherStuff` then just delete the `let` lines where you declare properties for them in your struct. Also you can delete your `initFrom` and `decode` because the right thing will happen all by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First just delete everything you don't want:

```
struct WholeResponse: Codable {
    let data: [Fruit]

    struct Fruit: Codable {
        let name: String
        let price: Int
    }
}
```

Then, similar to what you had before, say

```
let response = try jsonDecoder.decode(WholeResponse.self, from: jsonData)
let fruits = response.data
```